# Query Results Not Accurate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which provides me with accurate results:

```
SELECT t.id
    FROM titles t
ORDER BY t.id
```

My results are:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

My second query also provides me with accurate results:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM titles t 
    JOIN subscriptions s
        ON t.id = s.title
WHERE s.user=2
```

Results:

```
10
11
14
```

So what I am trying to do is receive all the results from the first query that don't show up in the second query, so I run this:

```
SELECT t.id
    FROM titles t
ORDER BY t.id NOT IN 
(
SELECT t.id
FROM titles t 
    JOIN subscriptions s
        ON t.id = s.title
WHERE s.user=2 
);
```

But my results end up as this:

```
14
11
10
13
12
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any why is the order reversed in my second query?

Comment: The order is not reversed. Notice the first 3 rows: `14,11,10`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOT IN` should be a part of `WHERE` condition, not `ORDER BY` statement:

```
SELECT
    t.id
FROM
    titles t
WHERE
    t.id NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT t.id
        FROM titles t 
            JOIN subscriptions s
               ON t.id = s.title
        WHERE s.user=2 
    )
ORDER BY
    t.id
```

Comment: Wow that was a record for fastest response. Thanks!

Comment: The condition can be simplified to `t.id NOT IN (SELECT s.title FROM subscriptions s WHERE s.user = 2)` assuming `s.title` is `NOT NULL`